# How can i edit my code without setState() problem?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I have this code in my constructor:

```
this.state = {
  tests: [
    {
      question: "1",
      answer: "2",
      user: ""
    },
    {
      question: "1",
      answer: "2",
      user: ""
    },

  ],

};
```

I have edit function where I read event value in my input:

```
  edit(id, event) {
    this.state.tests[id].user = event.target.value;
    this.setState({tests:this.state.tests});

  }
```

But es give me this warning:

> Do not mutate state directly. Use `setState()` 
>   react/no-direct-mutation-state

What can i do in this case? Maybe somehow change the line with the assignment `event.target.value` into `setState()`?

Comment: Create a copy of state and then mutate the copy.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `map()` to create copy of `tests`

```
edit(id, event) {
    const user = event.target.value;
    const tests = this.state.tests.map((x,i) =>  i === id ? {...x, user} : x);
    this.setState({tests});
}
```

Answer (score 1):

One way I tend to go is to make a copy of the array first and then change an item in it, or change the array itself, and then set the state

```
var tests = this.state.tests.slice(0);
tests[id].user = event.target.value;
this.setState({tests:tests});
```

You may want to deep-clone the array in some cases, sometimes not.

Comment: This is not correct. You will still have a reference because array is array of objects.

Comment: Not all react components require making deep copies of everything.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct, that the problem is with the line:

```
this.state.tests[id].user = event.target.value;
```

That's the point where you are mutating your state directly.

You have a few options.

You can "clone" the array first and then update it:

```
const newTests = [...this.state.tests];
newTests[id].user = event.target.value;
this.setState({tests: newTests});
```

You could also use [`immutability-helper`](https://github.com/kolodny/immutability-helper):

```
const {value} = event.target;
this.setState(prevState => update(prevState, {[id]: {user: {$set: value}}}));
```

In this example, you need to extract `value` from your event, because it's not safe to access event values in asynchronous calls after an event has been handled.

Answer (score 0):

```
edit(id, event) {
    var newNote = {...this.state.tests[id]}
    newNote.user = event.target.value
    this.setState({ tests: [...this.state.tests, newNote]})
}
```

Comment: Please explain your answer thoroughly.

Answer (score 0):

When state is not heavy, I use the following codes:

```js
edit (id, event) {
  const cp = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.state.tests))
  cp[id].user = event.target.value
  this.setState({ tests: cp })
}
```

Update: I found [Immer](https://github.com/immerjs/immer#reactsetstate-example) solves it perfectly.

```js
import produce from 'immer'

edit (id, event) {
  this.setState(
    produce(draft => draft.tests[id].user = event.target.value)
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, when you try to set a the new state using the data from previous state you have to use the updater as a function
https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate

```
const edit = (id, event) => {
  this.setState((prevState) => {
    const tests = [...prevState.tests];
    tests[id] = {
      ...tests[id],
      user: event.target.value
    };
    return {
      ...prevState,
      tests
    };
  });
};
```